# Get unique row with distinct multiple column in oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

Hi I have a tables tag which is like

```
id   loc_id   org_id   comp1   comp2   comp3   comp4  paper_id
1      5        4       A        C       B     (null)    1
2      6        3       F        D       E     (null)    1
3      5        4       C        B       A     (null)    1
4      6        3       E        F       D     (null)    1
```

I want to get a result like

```
id   loc_id   org_id   comp1   comp2   comp3   comp4  paper_id
3      5        4       C        B       A     (null)    1
4      6        3       E        F       D     (null)    1
```

Note I want a unique row having max id with distinct comp1, comp2, comp3, comp4 value inspite their column name but value should be same.

e.g if 1st row has A, B, C in comp1, comp2 & comp3 respectively
and    2nd row has C, B, A in comp1, comp2 & comp3 respectively
I want a single row.

I tried below query and this is not returning unique rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT loc_id, org_id, comp1, comp2, comp3, comp4, MAX(id)
  FROM tags t
  WHERE t.paper_id = 1
  GROUP BY loc_id, org_id, comp1, comp2, comp3, comp4;
```

Please help thanks.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: My query is not working

Comment: You are facing some error or rows are not selected?

Comment: I am getting all 4 rows from my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@marmite-bomber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037561/get-unique-row-with-distinct-multiple-column-in-oracle-table/52056523#answer-52039677) following query worked for me,

```
SELECT comp_key, loc_id, org_id, max_id, 1, sysdate, sysdate
FROM (
  SELECT comp_key, max(id) max_id
  FROM (
    WITH t1 AS (
      SELECT t.id, t.loc_id, t.org_id, nvl(comp1,0) comp FROM tags t WHERE t.paper_id = 1 AND t.paper_id IS NOT NULL UNION 
      SELECT t.id, t.loc_id, t.org_id, nvl(comp2,0) comp FROM tags t WHERE t.paper_id = 1 AND t.paper_id IS NOT NULL UNION
      SELECT t.id, t.loc_id, t.org_id, nvl(comp3,0) comp FROM tags t WHERE t.paper_id = 1 AND t.paper_id IS NOT NULL UNION
      SELECT t.id, t.loc_id, t.org_id, nvl(comp1,0) comp FROM tags t WHERE t.paper_id = 1 AND t.paper_id IS NOT NULL
    )
    SELECT t1.id, t1.loc_id loc_id, t1.org_id org_id, listagg(comp,',') within group (ORDER BY comp) AS comp_key
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY t1.id, t1.loc_id, t1.org_id
  )
  GROUP BY comp_key, loc_id, org_id
) t2, tags tg
WHERE tg.id = t2.max_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the frst step concatenate the `compN` columns in a given order.

You'll use `LISTAGG` - note that you use the *delimiter* and `NVL` function to make the result unique - you **don't** want to interpret (A,A,null,null) as a duplicate to (AA,null,null,null)

```
with t1 as (
select id, nvl(comp1,'-') comp from test union all
select id, nvl(comp2,'-') comp from test union all
select id, nvl(comp3,'-') comp from test union all
select id, nvl(comp4,'-') comp from test)
select id,
listagg(comp,',') within group (order by comp) as comp_key
from t1
group by id
order by 2
;


       ID COMP_KEY                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
---------- --------
         3 -,A,B,C
         1 -,A,B,C
         4 -,D,E,F
         2 -,D,E,F
```

The rest is as simple as group on the `COMP_KEY` and select some row from your source.

Here is an example selecting the highest `ID` per group (see `max(id)`in `t3`subquery).

```
with t1 as (
select id, nvl(comp1,'-') comp from test union all
select id, nvl(comp2,'-') comp from test union all
select id, nvl(comp3,'-') comp from test union all
select id, nvl(comp4,'-') comp from test),
t2 as (
select id,
listagg(comp,',') within group (order by comp) as comp_key
from t1
group by id
), t3 as (
select comp_key, max(id) id from t2
group  by comp_key)
select * from test 
where id in (select id from t3)
order by id
;
```

.

```
        ID     LOC_ID     ORG_ID COMP1 COMP2 COMP3 COMP4        PAPER_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ----- ----- ---------- ----------
         3          5          4 C     B     A                         1 
         4          6          3 E     F     D                         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; See if it suits your needs.

In order to do that, I'm going to create a function which sorts 4 IN parameters (representing `comp1, ..., comp4` from your sample data).

```
SQL> create or replace function f_sort(p1 in varchar2, p2 in varchar2,
  2                                    p3 in varchar2, p4 in varchar2)
  3  return varchar2
  4  is
  5    /* sorts IN parameters. For example: if IN parameters are a, d, c, b
  6       then RETVAL = a:b:c:d
  7    */
  8    retval varchar2(200);
  9  begin
 10    with temp (p) as
 11      (select p1 from dual union all select p2 from dual union all
 12       select p3 from dual union all select p4 from dual
 13      )
 14    select listagg(p, ':') within group (order by p)
 15      into retval
 16    from temp;
 17
 18    return retval;
 19  end;
 20  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

What do I need it for? To select `MAX(ID)` for equal combinations of `comp1, ..., comp4` values - as you described it (that's done in the `inter` CTE, below in a query).

```
SQL> with test (id, loc_id, org_id, comp1, comp2, comp3, comp4) as
  2  (select 1, 5, 4, 'a', 'c', 'b', null from dual union all
  3   select 2, 6, 3, 'f', 'd', 'e', null from dual union all
  4   select 3, 5, 4, 'c', 'b', 'a', null from dual union all
  5   select 4, 6, 3, 'e', 'f', 'd', null from dual
  6  ),
  7  inter as
  8  (select max(id) maxid, f_sort(comp1, comp2, comp3, comp4) srt
  9   from test
 10   group by f_sort(comp1, comp2, comp3, comp4)
 11  )
 12  select t.*
 13  from test t join inter i on i.maxid = t.id
 14  order by t.id;

        ID     LOC_ID     ORG_ID COMP1 COMP2 COMP3 COMP4
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ----- ----- -----
         3          5          4 c     b     a
         4          6          3 e     f     d

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get your desired results by grouping `greatest`, `least` functions, and their `mean`(average values) by contribution of ascii function which converts the related columns to integers :

```
select * 
  from tags
 where id in 
  (
  select max(id)
    from tags
   group by least(ascii(comp1),ascii(comp2),ascii(comp3)),
         greatest(ascii(comp1),ascii(comp2),ascii(comp3)),
         (least(ascii(comp1),ascii(comp2),ascii(comp3))+
          greatest(ascii(comp1),ascii(comp2),ascii(comp3)))/2
  );
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1d74/17)